# Traverse a nested json object and insert the keys and values into two related tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm passing the following json structure to my procedure:

`{questA: [[a1, a2], [a3, a4]], questB: [[b1, b2], [b2, b4]...]}`

I would like to go over all the 'quest' keys (questA, questB...) and insert each key name to one table and it's value sets to another table in multiple rows so each set (a1, a2) has it's own row plus foreign key field to it's parent quest key.

```
quest
-------
id
key

questValues
-------------
id
val
val
quest_id
foreign key (quest_id) references quest(id)
```

I've tried something like:

```
FOR key, val IN SELECT * FROM jasonb_each_text(myJson) LOOP
...
END LOOP;
```

But it loops over everything so the val arrays are just plain text now. I thought about chaining selects with one of the json literal functions but I'm unsure about the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed do this with chaining the output various JSON functions:

```
with input (parameter) as (
  values ('{"questA": [["a1", "a2"], ["a3", "a4"]], "questB": [["b1", "b2"], ["b2", "b4"]]}'::jsonb)
), elements as (
  select j.quest, k.answer
  from input i 
    cross join lateral jsonb_each(i.parameter) as j(quest,vals)
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j.vals) as k(answer)
), new_quests as (
  insert into quest ("key")
  select distinct quest
  from elements
  returning *
)  
insert into quest_values (val1, val2, quest_id)
select e.answer ->> 0 as val1,
       e.answer ->> 1 as val2,
       nq.id as quest_id
from new_quests nq
  join elements e on e.quest = nq.key;
```

The first step ("elements") turns the JSON value into rows that can be used as the source of the INSERT statements. It returns this:

```
quest  | answer      
-------+-------------
questA | ["a1", "a2"]
questA | ["a3", "a4"]
questB | ["b1", "b2"]
questB | ["b2", "b4"]
```

The next step inserts the unique values of the `quest` column into the `quest` table and returns the generated IDs.

And the final statement joins the generated IDs with the rows from the first step and extracts the two array elements as two values. It uses that query as the source to insert into the `quest_values` table.

Inside a procedure you obviously don't need the part that generates the sample data, so it would look something like this:

```
with elements as (
  select j.quest, k.answer
  from jsonb_each(the_parameter) as j(quest,vals)
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(j.vals) as k(answer)
), new_quests as (
  insert into quest ("key")
  select distinct quest
  from elements
  returning *
)  
insert into quest_values (val1, val2, quest_id)
select e.answer ->> 0 as val1,
       e.answer ->> 1 as val2,
       nq.id as quest_id
from new_quests nq
  join elements e on e.quest = nq.key;
```

Where `the_parameter` is the JSONB parameter passed to your procedure.

Online example: https://rextester.com/NBJIK44025

Comment: How do we get e.'something' defined. Like the 'e.answer' I would expect an 'as e' defined some where, I guess that's what really confuses me. Is it in the returning *? also does the ->>0,1 refers to the index in the list?

Comment: `join elements e` defines the alias `e`  and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html explains the `->>` operator

Comment: I'm getting an "invalid transaction termination near commit;" error when I try to use the code in a procedure and commit the transaction. I haven't changed the code just added the right commit; and end; $$ plus the start of the procedure.

Comment: @S.Schenk: that has nothing to do with the statement, but with the limited possibilities of transaction handling in a Postgres stored procedure and is a completely different querstion. Make sure you did not start a transaction before calling the procedure (e.g. turn autocommit on)

Comment: autocommit is not on and the code in the answer is the only code that's present in the procedure. So I'm completely unsure what it can be.

Comment: Autocommit must be **on** when you use transactions inside procedures - otherwise the caller will have already started a transaction. (but again this is totally unrelated to your question here)